# Core Data Update/AppStore update

Tags: xcode, core-data, migration

I have an app in the AppStore which includes its own database. This database can be updated by the user.

My question is, if I update with a new version y app, via AppStore, how can I mix old data with new data? I don't need to change the model, only mix data.

Do I need to do a "Lightweight Migration"? Is there any way to mix automatically all data?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers here about `pre-loading` data into coreData that might address your question.

You basically want to ship a database (store) with your app. This store will contain "your data". At run-time you merge "your data" with the users data into the apps database. The app can then use the merged data